# MongoDB update collection's data

Tags: mongodb

I try to update an MongoDB data by using this code:
`db.medicines.update({"_id":"586a048e34e5c12614a7424a"}, {$set: {amount:'3'}})`

but unfortantly the query does not recognize the selector `"_id":"586a048e34e5c12614a7424a"`, even if its exists.
Its succsed when I change the key to another like: `name`,`rate` and etc..

there is a special way to use update with `_id` parameter?

Thanks a head.

Comment: Try `db.medicines.update({"_id":ObjectId("586a048e34e5c12614a7424a")}, {$set: {amount:'3'}})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_id` will be the unique `ObjectId` that mongodb generates for every document before inserting it. The query dint work because `_id` is an `ObjectId` and `"586a048e34e5c12614a7424a"` is a `String`. You need to wrap `_id` with `ObjectId()`.

If you're using mongodb query

```
db.medicines.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("586a048e34e5c12614a7424a")
}, {
  $set: {
    amount: '3'
  }
});
```

If you are using `mongoose`. You can use [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

```
db.medicines.findByIdAndUpdate({
  "_id": "586a048e34e5c12614a7424a"
}, {
  $set: {
    amount: '3'
  }
});
```